# Typeclasses and subtyping

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit, subtyping

I have the following code defining a type class.

```
trait Foo[T] {
  def toFoo(x: T): String
}

trait Foos {
  def toFoo[T](f: T => String): Foo[T] = new Foo[T] {
    def toFoo(x: T): String = f(x)
  }
}

object Foo extends Foos {
  def toFoo[A: Foo](a: A) = implicitly[Foo[A]].toFoo(a)
  implicit def AToFoo: Foo[A] = toFoo { c =>
    "A"
   }
  implicit def BToFoo[T]: Foo[B] = toFoo { c  => 
    "B"
  }

  implicit def ListToFoo[T: Foo]: Foo[List[T]] = toFoo { c =>
    c.map(toFoo(_)).
  }
}

class A
class B extends A
```

Now if I have if I do `toFoo(List(new A, new B)` I get `List("A", "A")` instead of `List("A", "B")`. How can I ensure that the `BtoFoo` method is used rather than `AToFoo` for classes with type `B`?

Comment: What type do you expect `List(new A, new B)` to have?

Comment: I expect `List(new A, new B)` to have type `List[A]`

Comment: in that case, when you map `toFoo` over the `List[A]`, it apparently first performs `implicitly[Foo[A]]` and gets the `AToFoo` implicit def, and uses it for each element. Typeclasses are designed for type-directed dispatch, not for value-directed dispatch, so they don't always play nicely with subtyping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

implicit resolution is a purely compile-time mechanism. The easy way to distinguish between subtypes here is to match inside the implicit. Remove `BToFoo` altogether and have instead the `A` version deal with both cases

```
implicit val AIsFoo : Foo[A] = toFoo { 
  case b: B => "B"
  case a: A => "A"
}
```

Of course, it is also possible to delegate to a method for part of the hierarchy. You may delegate to a method in `A`, overidde in `B`, and still have the typeclass work for List, where you cannot add a method.

You may also consider declaring `Foo` contravariant.

Comment: I have implemented your suggestion using pattern matching but it doesn't seem very elegant to me having to check for all the children of `A` in `AIsFoo` rather than being able to write `XIsFoo` directly for any child `X` of A.
How does declaring `Foo` contravariant work? I tried
`trait Foo[-T] {
  def toFoo(x: T): String
}`